# What is the utility of creating a full-depth Visual Sitemap?

Tags: info-visualisation, information-architecture, sitemap, information-design

I’m a programmer that is new to UX and have a potential web project that has probably ~5k pages.

What type of information could I take away and benefit from this tedious exercise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with the above response conceptually..however, using the [right tool](https://visualsitemaps.com) to automate the tedious task of generating a visual sitemap of 5k pages would perhaps be both a more efficient and thorough solution for your needs.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to have a full sitemap of 5k pages.

You want a **summarized view** of your website.

Below is a sitemap I had to do for a website. The list has a pagination, so many pages can be displayed in this one.
[image]

Showing too many complex interactions or links between page is not necessary. You should have a clear understanding of the website's structure when looking at the sitemap, but it's not necessary to be exhaustive.